# Calculating disctance between 2 coordinates using click events

Tags: python, tkinter

I can display an image on my panel, what I need is to click on 2 spots in the picture and calculate the distance between them. I am having trouble with the event handler and how to use it similarly to a scanner in Java. For example, if I run the program and click once somewhere in the image, it runs all 3 methods at once which leads to give an error.

```
root = Tk()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("target.PNG"))
#img = cv2.imread("target.PNG")
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

def leftClick(event):
   global x0,y0
   x0 = event.x
   y0 = event.y
   return x0, y0

panel.bind("<Button-1>", leftClick)

def rightClick(event):
   global x1,y1
   x1 = event.x
   y1 = event.y
   return x1, y1    

 panel.bind("<Button-1>", rightClick)

def getDistance(event):
    distance = math.sqrt( ((x0-x1)**2)+((y0-y1)**2) )
    print(distance)

panel.bind("<Button-1>", getDistance)
root.mainloop()
```

What I'm looking for is to execute each step once at a time. The final step to calculate the distance can be done outside a method it doesn't really matter. I just need to get the coordinates to work first. Please let me know how I could proceed to solve this.

Comment: The Pythagoras theorem is mandatory to have two components. You can calculate the measurement value in each second click. You must collect the clicked points in a list, and then scroll the list to the left each click.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This Two:

**Process 1(Uses mouse left click, right click, middle(scroll) click):**

The following code takes

(x0, y0) from mouse-left-click

(x1, y1) from mouse-right-click

and then prints distance between them on mouse-middle(scroll)-click

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import math

root = Tk()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Logo.png"))
panel = Label(root, image=img)
panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
x0 = 0
y0 = 0
x1 = 0
y1 = 0


def leftClick(event):
    global x0, y0
    x0 = event.x
    y0 = event.y
    # return [x0, y0]


panel.bind("<Button-1>", leftClick)


def rightClick(event):
    global x1, y1
    x1 = event.x
    y1 = event.y
    # return x1, y1


panel.bind("<Button-3>", rightClick)


def getDistance(event):
    global x0, y0, x1, y1
    distance = math.sqrt(((x0 - x1)**2)+((y0 - y1)**2))
    print(distance)


panel.bind("<Button-2>", getDistance)
root.mainloop()
```

**Process 2(Uses only mouse left click):**

The following code takes

(x0, y0) from first mouse-left-click

(x1, y1) from second mouse-left-click

and then prints distance between them on third mouse-left-click

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import math

root = Tk()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Logo.png"))
panel = Label(root, image=img)
panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
counter = 0
x0 = 0
x1 = 0
y0 = 0
y1 = 0


def getDistance(event):
    global counter, x0, y0, x1, y1
    if counter == 0:
        x0 = event.x
        y0 = event.y
        counter += 1
    elif counter == 1:
        x1 = event.x
        y1 = event.y
        counter += 1
    elif counter == 2:
        distance = math.sqrt(((x0 - x1)**2)+((y0 - y1)**2))
        print(distance)
        counter = 0


panel.bind("<Button-1>", getDistance)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a demo for count distance from a start point to a end point, which takes a DRAG operation with mouse left button.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import math
start_point_x, start_point_y, end_point_x, end_point_y = 0, 0, 0, 0

def mouse_left_down_detection(event):
    global start_point_x, start_point_y
    start_point_x = event.x
    start_point_y = event.y

def mouse_left_release_detection(event):
    global end_point_x, end_point_y
    end_point_x = event.x
    end_point_y = event.y
    print(start_point_x, start_point_y, end_point_x, end_point_y)
    print(get_instance(start_point_x, start_point_y, end_point_x, end_point_y))

def get_instance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt((pow(abs(x2-x1), abs(x2-x1))+pow(abs(y2-y1), abs(y2-y1))))

image_path = "andy.jpg"
root = tk.Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image_path))
panel = tk.Label(root, image=img)
# Bind event mouse left down
panel.bind("<Button-1>", mouse_left_down_detection)
# Bind event mouse left release and calculate distance
panel.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", mouse_left_release_detection)
panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
root.mainloop()
```